# How to structure web data in table

Tags: r, web, web-scraping

My first R script scrapes a web table like this:

```
    RACE2<U+00A0>CLS5<U+00A0>1200M<U+00A0>ST<U+00A0>GRS<U+00A0>ARATE:(0-40)<U+00A0>GING:FAST
```

How can I change it to row and column data frame like below

[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg2Ff.png)

First 6 column I need to add my column name, Last 2 I use the name from web data

How I can make this done

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't, because the data is too messy at this point.

If you ran this line to replace the `<U+00A0>` s

```
gsub("<U\\+00A0>", " ", "RACE2<U+00A0>CLS5<U+00A0>1200M<U+00A0>ST<U+00A0>GRS<U+00A0>ARATE:(0-40)<U+00A0>GING:FAST")
```

you'd get

`RACE2 CLS5 1200M ST GRS ARATE:(0-40) GING:FAST`

and you can continue from there

```
library(tidyverse)
gsub("<U\\+00A0>", "\\\n", "RACE2<U+00A0>CLS5<U+00A0>1200M<U+00A0>ST<U+00A0>GRS<U+00A0>ARATE:(0-40)<U+00A0>GING:FAST") %>%
        str_split(pattern="\\\n", simplify)
```

which yields

```
[[1]]
[1] "RACE2"        "CLS5"         "1200M"        "ST"           "GRS"          "ARATE:(0-40)"
[7] "GING:FAST"
```

but I think your data contains too many missing attribute names, too few ":" separators, and it's impossible to reliably  detect NA values.